# Setting parent state (object) from child causes constant re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks

I have a parent component with a couple children components inside of it. I want to be able to set the status of the parent depending on the state of the children.

For example, imagine a parent component with 3 children who all get their status from a server. They then set the status of the parent so that the parent can see if all children have issues, or just a couple for example.

Parent:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [hasIssues, setHasIssues] = useState({
    "child-item-1": false,
    "child-item-2": false,
    "child-item-3": false
  });

  const issuesHandler = (childName, childStatus) => {
    setHasIssues({ ...hasIssues, [childName]: childStatus });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(hasIssues, null, 2)}</pre>
      <div>
        <ChildItemOne issuesHandler={issuesHandler} />
        <ChildItemTwo issuesHandler={issuesHandler} />
        <ChildItemThree issuesHandler={issuesHandler} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

A child example:

```
const ChildItemOne = ({ issuesHandler }) => {
  // Imagine this is actually retrieved from a server
  const hasIssues = Math.random() <= 0.75;

  issuesHandler("child-item-1", hasIssues);

  return <div>{`child-item-1: ${hasIssues}`}</div>;
};
```

Of course this example will exceed the maximum update depth. I have tried preventing this by using the following for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  issuesHandler("child-item-1", hasIssues);
}, [hasIssues, issuesHandler]);
```

but this still does not have the intended result as the state is still constantly updated, but without it exceeding the maximum update depth: [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-cherry-dgzp0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

I have also tried using `useCallback`, which didn't do anything. Changing the dependencies of `useEffect` to an empty array (ESLint doesn't let me do that locally anyway), didn't work either:

[image]

What's the best way to set a parent's state from a child component without it causing constant re-rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `const hasIssues = Math.random() <= 0.75;` into the `useEffect()` callback. This will prevent the rerender loop, since the value will only be generated once.

This will also simulate the call to the server better, since it will only happen once, when the component is mounted.

```
const ChildItemOne = ({ issuesHandler, hasIssues }) => {      
  useEffect(() => {
    // Imagine this is actually retrieved from a server
    issuesHandler("child-item-1", Math.random() <= 0.75);
  }, [issuesHandler]);

  return <div>{`child-item-1: ${hasIssues}`}</div>;
};
```

The parent should also pass `hasIssues` back to the children wrap `issuesHandler` with `useCallback()`, and use the updater callback in `setHasIssues()`. This will prevent the `issuesHandler` from being recreated on each render, which will in turn cause the children's `useEffect()` to be called, and so on...

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [hasIssues, setHasIssues] = useState({
    "child-item-1": false,
    "child-item-2": false,
    "child-item-3": false
  });

  const issuesHandler = useCallback((childName, childStatus) => {
    setHasIssues(state => ({ ...state, [childName]: childStatus }))
  }, [setHasIssues]);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(hasIssues, null, 2)}</pre>
      <div>
        <ChildItemOne issuesHandler={issuesHandler} hasIssues={hasIssues['child-item-1']} />
        <ChildItemTwo issuesHandler={issuesHandler} hasIssues={hasIssues['child-item-2']} />
        <ChildItemThree issuesHandler={issuesHandler} hasIssues={hasIssues['child-item-3']} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Live example:

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useEffect } = React;

const ChildItemOne = ({ issuesHandler, hasIssues }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Imagine this is actually retrieved from a server
    issuesHandler("child-item-1", Math.random() <= 0.75);
  }, [issuesHandler]);

  return <div>{`child-item-1: ${hasIssues}`}</div>;
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [hasIssues, setHasIssues] = useState({
    "child-item-1": false,
    "child-item-2": false,
    "child-item-3": false
  });

  const issuesHandler = useCallback((childName, childStatus) => {
    setHasIssues(state => ({ ...state, [childName]: childStatus }))
  }, [setHasIssues]);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(hasIssues, null, 2)}</pre>
      <div>
        <ChildItemOne issuesHandler={issuesHandler} hasIssues={hasIssues['child-item-1']} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: If you declare `hasIssues` in `useEffect` then it's not going to be available outside of it. It also didn't seem to solve the issue of the component re-rendering as the state keeps on changing.

Comment: Since your passing `hasIssues` value to the parent, you can get it back from the parent via props. It does solve the issue, since `useEffect()` is not dependant on `hasIssues` anymore. However, the  `issuesHandler` should also be memoized.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case for useContext. React Context is used to provide access to state/function for both parent and children components without the use of the callback hell.

First create a dummy context component somewhere in the app, then import it to the Parent component and use it to wrap around components that need the pass down. And then instead of passing your states/functions to the child, you just pass it to the context component.

In your child components, you can access those data by using useContext.

issueContext.js (dummy context file)

```
// app/context/issueContext.js
import { createContext } from 'react';    
export default createContext();
```

parent component

```
import IssueContext from 'issueContext';

const Parent = () => {
  const [hasIssues, setHasIssues] = useState({ ... });    
  const issuesHandler = (childName, childStatus) => { ... };

  return (
    <>
      <IssueContext.Provider value={{ hasIssues, setHasIssues, issuesHandler }} >     
          <ChildItemOne />
          <ChildItemTwo />
          <ChildItemThree />
      </IssueContext>         
    </>
  );
};
```

Child component

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import IssueContext from 'issueContext';

const ChildItemOne = () => {

  const {hasIssues, setHasIssues, issuesHandler} = useContext(IssueContext);

  if (something wrong) {
    sethasIssues();

    issuesHandler("child-item-1", hasIssues);  
  }
};
```

Comment: I think this could be a solution, but it seems a bit much creating an entire context for something that is just 1 level deep (could just be me). I'll try it out tomorrow and see if it works!